# Google Sheets Script: That Searches For Previous Match in Memo and If Found Automaticly Fills In A Category

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to edit a google sheets budgeting template. I need a script that looks at previous memos that have been assigned a category and will match newly entered memos with a category if it has already been matched above.

Memos consist of multiple words and a match should only happen if the exact words are present.

[What Spreadsheet Looks Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiq8R.png)

[Spreadsheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10PUweldLxAfvt36kfUyxQflx9hslzQFinCqkxMMwYBU/edit?usp=sharing)

I don't know if this is relevant but the template consists of multiple sheets.

I found someone else's code ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/aspirebudgeting/comments/ealytv/auto_fill_category_script_in_transactions_after/)) trying to do what I do but I cant get it to work. This Is what they did...

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Aspire Budgeting')
      .addItem('Auto Fill Category. Click on first empty Category in Transaction first', 'autoFillCategory')
      .addToUi();
}

function autoFillCategory() {
  // to use this script import new Transactions then click on the first empty category in Transactions.  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // startRow is off set by 1 in getDataRange
  var startRow = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow() - 1;
  // categoryColumn is off set by 1 in getDataRange
  var categoryColumn = sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn() -1;
  var memoColumn = categoryColumn + 2
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
    
  // Check to make sure the current cell is set to Transactions -> Categories
  if (sheet.getName() == "Transactions" && data[6][categoryColumn] == "Category" && startRow > 8) {
    for (var currRow = startRow; currRow < data.length; currRow++) {
      // memoValue to search for
      var memoValue = data[currRow][memoColumn];
      
      //  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(currRow);
      var previousCategory = "";
      //Search for the previous instance of memoValue.
      for (var i = 0; i < currRow; i++) {
        var row = data[i];
        if (row[memoColumn] == memoValue) {
          previousCategory=row[categoryColumn];
          sheet.getRange(currRow + 1,categoryColumn + 1).setValue(previousCategory);
          break;
        }
      }
    }   
  } else { 
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Before running this script import new transactions then click on the first empty category in transactions you want to search for.");
    return;
  }
}
```

I dont really have much coding experience so I don't really where Im going wrong

Comment: What are you searching for? Where is it found? and what do you wish to do with it when you find it.  Your image isn't that useful since it does not show the lines and columns

Comment: @Cooper Here is a link to the spreadsheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10PUweldLxAfvt36kfUyxQflx9hslzQFinCqkxMMwYBU/edit?usp=sharing and here is one the the reddit post with the original code https://www.reddit.com/r/aspirebudgeting/comments/ealytv/auto_fill_category_script_in_transactions_after/ all I want to do is what the reddit code is intended to do but I cant figure out how to get it to work

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow links to to spreadsheets